# Check that document has fully saved in mongo collection before continuing

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, pymongo

I have a system where a client submits jobs to a server and later on, downloads the jobs from the server.

I am writing a test where the client submits a job and then tries to download the job. Because these two functions are happening one after another, I believe the script is trying to download jobs faster than they have been saved in MongoEngine. This is the flow

```
  CLIENT                   SERVER                        MONGODB
submit_job(id)       -> recieve_job(id)
     |                  save_job_in_mongo_engine(id)  (Not actually saved yet...)
     |               <- return status.200
download_job(id)     -> job_info(id)
     |                  get_job_in_mongo_engine(id)   (Not saved yet...)
     |               <- return None
job_not_downloaded()         |
fail_test()                  |
                             |                        (Job now saved in db)
```

If I delay the downloading of the job by 10th of a second or so, or try and download multiple times before failing the test, then the test works fine. However, ideally, I would like to asynchronously wait for the document to be saved in the collection on the server before returning the `status.200` message.

How can I asynchronously wait for a document to be fully saved in a collection in mongo engine?

Comment: I've never used them, but I'm wondering if change streams or currentOp/$currentOp may be useful here to indicate when the job is completed.

Comment: @rickhg12hs It was actually to do with me using `.save()` rather than `.update()` on the server side. When I used `.update()` the code worked fine. Thanks though!